# Doctrine Migrations not creating join table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I'm trying to create a join table between two entities using Doctrine ORM and the Symfony maker bundle.

The two entities are `User` and `Member`. A `User` should be able to reference multiple `Member` entities, and `Member` entities can be referenced by multiple users.

User:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
        public readonly string $username,

        #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Member::class, mappedBy: 'name')]
        #[ORM\JoinTable(
            name: 'tracked_members',
            joinColumns: [
                new ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'user', referencedColumnName: 'username'),
            ],
            inverseJoinColumns: [
                new ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'member', referencedColumnName: 'name'),
            ],
        )]
        public ArrayCollection $tracked_members,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Member:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\MemberRepository;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MemberRepository::class)]
class Member
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
        public readonly string $name,
    ) {
    }
}
```

However, when I run `./bin/console make:migration`, I receive the following migration class with no warnings or errors indicating a problem:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20220705021447 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE member (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(name))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(username))');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE member');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE user');
    }
}
```

Why isn't the SQL to create the join table `tracked_users` being added to the migration class?

Other relevant info:

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| PHP | 8.1.7 |
| SQLite | 3.37.0 |
| doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle | 3.2.2 |
| doctrine/orm | 2.13.3 |
| symfony/maker-bundle | 1.43.0 |

Comment: We do not see the User class code, and your migration seems to create a primary key named "chat_id" when your referenceColumnName says "username". Could you add the user class code?

Comment: @Maniax the `User` class is the first code block (it's been there from the beginning). I corrected the migration class.

Comment: My bad, sorry. But now I really don't know how chat_id got there. My point was why would the generated migration be wrong? If you correct a field you may aswell add the join table. Can you pass the validate-schema without errors?

Comment: @Maniax thanks for the clue about `validate-schema`: I didn't know about that command. I was able to figure out the issue using that to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this to work. Even though PHP 8.1 supports nested attributes, and `#[JoinTable]` has `joinColumns` and `inverseJoinColumns` parameters, you **must** specify `#[JoinColumn]` and `#[InverseJoinColumn]` as top-level attributes.

The following updated `User` entity generates the expected result:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
        public readonly string $username,

        #[ORM\JoinColumn('username', referencedColumnName: 'username')]
        #[ORM\InverseJoinColumn('member', referencedColumnName: 'name')]
        #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'tracked_members')]
        #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Member::class)]
        public ArrayCollection $tracked_members,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Resulting Migration class:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20220705021447 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE member (name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(name))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE user (username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(username))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE tracked_members (username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, member VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(username, member))');
        $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_CD2594E8F85E0677 ON tracked_members (username)');
        $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_CD2594E870E4FA78 ON tracked_members (member)');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE member');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE user');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE tracked_members');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add `inversedBy`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\MemberRepository;
use App\Entity\User;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MemberRepository::class)]
class Member
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
        #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'tracked_members')] 
        public readonly string $name,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: No change. `tracked_members` table is not added to the Migration class.